# Eclipse Dynamic Web Project -> source folders on build path blank

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]

nothing problem start New Dynamic Web Project create

[image]

nothing source folders on build path  why????

[image]

And it failed making project

wth is failed while installing Java 1.8?

please save me

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with Eclipse 20.04 and I'd found a solution in this PDF:

[How to develop a Java web project with Eclipse](https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/3/3f/How_to_use_eclipse_to_develop_java_web_project.pdf)

In short, the steps are these:

1. Select "File" / "New" / "Project..." / "Dynamic Web Project"
2. In "Dynamic Web Project" dialog, enter the project name (ie: MyProj)
3. Click "Next >"
4. In the "Java" dialog, which have the empty folder, click the icon of the empty folder, click "Edit..." on right pane, write "src" and click "OK"
5. On the lower side, under "Default output folder" write "build/classes"
6. Click "Next >"
7. In "Web Module" dialog, for "Content directory" write "WebContent"
8. Check "Generate web.xml deployment descriptor" if you like
9. Click "Finish"

...and the project should be created with this structure:

```
<root>
      build
           classes
      src
      WebContent
                META-INF
                        MANIFEST.XML
                WEB-INF
                       lib
                       web.xml
```